# Start a WS connection on a server that's being accessed by SSH port forwarding

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have an EC2 Instance(A) and a RaspberryPi(B). I want to access a HTML page in B.
Here are the steps I did:

1. Created a simple `index.html` in B that connects to a WebSocket running on 5443 also in B
2. Served it with SimpleHTTPServer on port 1337
3. Created a port forwarding. When I access A:9000 it should redirect to B:1337. Used: `ssh -f -N -R 9000:127.0.0.1:1337 A`

With that I'm able to access my `index.html` page, however it fails when trying to connect to the WebSocket server with

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5553/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

When I use VNC to connect to B, and access the browser in localhost:1337 I'm able to see the page AND the WebSocket connection succeeds.

I'm not sure why it fails when I try to access it through the EC2 instance. Does anyone have any clues on what might be the problem? thanks

**All ports are open in my EC2 instance

Answer (score 0):

Even though I was port forwarding, localhost:5553 wasn't the raspberry pi IP, was the EC2. I created a new port forwarding from 9001 in A to 5443 in B to tunnel the Websocket connection and it worked.